# Screen burn in monitor when connected to an iMac, but not when connected to a PC

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

When I connect a *DELL U2713HM ULTRASHARP 27"* as a secondary display for my iMac (DisplayPort), after less than 20 minutes i get horrible burn in; but the same setup (same brightness even, through DVI) with a PC produces no burn-in at all - even after hours of me accidentally forgetting an open bright window. How is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK, burn-in is permanent, so unless you're buying a new monitor every time this happens I suspect it's not actually burn-in.

Comment: @joeqwerty - you are absolutely correct; I used *burn-in* haphazardly, meaning only a temporary effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is [image persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence), not burn in.  It has to do with the clock frequency being sent to the display.  The higher drive signal is causing the monitor to pass higher current to the individual pixels in the screen. It is not permanent, and is not harmful to the screen.

An LCD works by sandwiching quartz crystals between two polarizing filters that are set 90 degrees apart.  Light cannot pass through polarizers arranged this way, but when electrical current is applied to the crystal between them, it twists so that the light can be guided through both polarizers and you can see it.  When the current is removed, they go back to their resting state, but it's not instantaneous.  They take time to relax.

Think of it like memory foam.  When you squeeze it, it takes a moment to return to its original shape.  If you squeeze harder, it takes longer.

I suspect it's more of a DisplayPort vs. DVI issue rather than a Mac vs. PC issue (although it could be; Macs use a higher gamma than PCs do).  I would try reversing the connections first to see if the problem trades places.  You could also try changing the color profile on the Mac (System Prefs -> Display -> Color).  If you hit the calibrate button, you can change the gamma manually.

Either way, it's probably just a Dell thing and there isn't much you can do about it.  I use Dell 2007FP 20" 4:3 screens on my computer at work, and the persistence effect is pretty bad.  My company's standard desktop config uses 22" NEC 16:9 displays and I don't notice the effect at all on those.  The only reason I use the Dells is because I need 3 of them :o)

Comment: That's very interesting to know; and yes, i meant a temporary persistence. "*The higher drive signal is causing the monitor to pass higher current to the individual crystals*" - is there a way to limit this effect on the mac by fiddling with software?

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the answer to your question, as I think I probably shoulda put it there in the first place.  Also for clarification, the drive signal to the pixels is a function of voltage regulation within the monitor's hardware and not something you can control with software.  It is possible to adjust the clock signal with some 3rd party overclockers' tools, but I would highly recommend against that.  I literally burned a monitor up many years ago playing with that stuff.